# Validate a field from form using the BindingResult :Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How to validate an integer type value in a form input using the BindingResult in spring?

When I try to validate the input I am getting an exception.I have gone through many posts but did not understand the concept completely.

The problem here isn't with validation, it is with the data binding. Data binding happens before validation, and validation is only invoked when all fields have been converted and bound correctly. In my case, the binding step is failing.Please correct me if I am wrong here.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label  th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:errors="age"
                    class="validation-message"></label>
            <input type="number" th:field="*{age}"
            placeholder="Age" class="form-control" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Code to map the request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
    if (userExists != null) {
        bindingResult
                .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                        "There is already a user registered with the email provided");
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
    } else {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "User has been registered succssfully");
        modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
        modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
        }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

User.class

```
@Column(name = "age")
@NotEmpty(message = "*age is mandatory")
private Integer age;
```

Exception:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'age'
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.throwExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:229) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorNoUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:310) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getConstraintValidatorInstanceForAutomaticUnwrapping(ConstraintTree.java:244) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your user class? What annotation have you used for age field?

Comment: @RSingh Added the code.

Comment: Not empty is  for Strings and collections. If you just want to make sure an Integer has some value, javax.validation.constraints.NotNull should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not empty constraint is used for Strings and collections.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotEmpty.html.

To verify if an Integer has some value, @NotNull constraint should be used.